# how to appromimately align unprecise time series data / curves?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, gps, pattern-matching

There are two similar time series data sets that share a common measurement, that however comes from two completely different sources:

- one is a classic GPS receiver (position, accurate **time**, somewhat accurate **speed** once per second) on a tractor
- the other is a logger device on the same tractor that has an internal real time **clock** and measures **speed**/distance by measuring **wheel rotation**. That device also tracks other sensor data and stores these values once per second.

**I'd like to combine these two data sources so that I can (as accurately as possible) combine GPS position and the additional logger sensor data.**

---

One aspect that might help here is that there will be some significant speed variations during the measurement as the tractor usually has to do 180-degree turns after 100-200 meters (i.e good detail for a better matching).

By plotting the speed data into two charts respectively (X-axis is time, Y-axis is speed), I think a human could pretty easily align the charts in a way so that they match nicely.

How can this be done in software? I expect there are known algorithms that solve this but it's hard to search for it if you don't know the right terms...

Anyway, the algorithm probably has to deal with these problems:

- the length of the data won't be equal (the two devices won't start/stop *exactly* at the same time - I expect at least 80% to overlap)
- the GPS clock is of course perfectly accurate, but the realtime clock of the logger may be way off (it has no synchronized time source), so that I can't simply match the time
- there might be slight variations in the measured speed due to the different measurement methods

A simple solution probably would find two matching extremes (allowing to interpolate the data in between), a better solution might be more flexible and even correct some "drifts"...

Comment: If you want to go into this in depth, look up Kalman Filtering. Note that the GPS speed is (as I understand it) estimated from the position reports.

Comment: I had a look at Kalman filters. There is even a [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kalmanjs) ready, but it seems rather a noise compensating algorithm and I don't understand how it applies to the problem described here?

Comment: Each input (GPS, etc) can be thought of as measurement + noise component (estimation errors). Estimation of aircraft position and velocity from multiple radar returns is a similar problem.